# Map Application in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new in iphone  developement.I am developing a map application which allows the user to select a particular area of a map(circular or rectangular area).To develop this application which is the best tool,Google maps API or Mapkit framework .Please any one give me a perfect way to develop this ,Is there any sample codes available..Thanks in advance......

Comment: Not an easy project as your first iPhone app.  Start with Apple's samples.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, if you're developing an iphone application and you want access to things like the users current location, you're going to want to use the MapKit framework.

Some googling on MapKit+tutorial will give you links like: [Playing with MapKit](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/03/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-2/).